# Open Solaris11 in Vagrant: Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 2222: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I use this Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "jonatasbaldin/solaris11"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"
  
end
```

The `vagrant up` is successful, but `vagrant ssh` exit with 255 return code with no output at all. To debug, I do

```
$ ssh -v vagrant@localhost -p 2222
```

I get:

```
$ ssh -v vagrant@localhost -p 2222
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mevatlave/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 267: Applying options for localhost
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 288: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mevatlave/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: compat_banner: no match: Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as 'vagrant'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/mevatlave/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 2222: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Tried many solutions from searches on the web with no luck. Any hint?

On the virtualbox tty, I get `sshd[1234]: fatal: no hostkey alg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SSH protocol, there are different types of keys and each type of key allows one or more signature algorithms.  The type of keys that are used here on the server side are RSA (`ssh-rsa`) and DSA (`ssh-dss`) keys.  With RSA keys, there are three kinds of signatures: `ssh-rsa` (SHA-1), `rsa-sha2-256` (SHA-256), and `rsa-sha2-512` (SHA-512).  Only the latter two types of signatures are secure; the older `ssh-rsa` signature type and all signatures for `ssh-dss` use SHA-1, which is obsolete and insecure.  (The size of the DSA keys used is also grossly inadequate by modern standards.)

Unfortunately, the VM you're using only supports insecure algorithms, so there's no secure way to connect to it.  The best thing to do is use a different image for a more secure operating system or a more secure configuration of the operating system.

If you absolutely must use this image, you can run `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -p 2222 vagrant@localhost` so that you can enable the insecure `ssh-rsa` algorithm and connect.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done with the help of bk2204:

In `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.ssh.config = "ssh_config"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  cat /path/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /export/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
SHELL
```

In `ssh_config`;

```
User vagrant
HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /path/to/solaris/id_dsa
```

But it's not sufficient to login with key pair, even if I modified sshd config:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```